# What's the cost of a Style merit?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, vampire-the-requiem-2e

I'm confused about the rules of Requiem 2e with respect to Style Merits.

As far as I can tell, Requiem 2e itself doesn't define the Style keyword, but there's this in the God-Machine Rules Update, pg. 158:

> Style Merits
>
> Merits marked as Style Merits allow access to specialized maneuvers. Each maneuver is a prerequisite for the next in its sequence. So if a Style Merit has a three-dot maneuver and a four-dot maneuver, you must purchase the three-dot version before accessing the four-dot.

The presentation seems to indicate this is a special rule for Style Merits, but I'm not clear on exactly what the difference is.

If I want to learn the first three moves of Kindred Dueling, do I need to pay…

A. 1 XP for Dueling •, 2 XP for Dueling ••, 3 XP for Dueling •••, all written as separate merits on my sheet, for a total cost of 6 XP?

B. 1 XP for Dueling •, 1 XP to upgrade it to Dueling ••, 1 XP to upgrade it to Dueling •••, for a total cost of 3 XP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a bit more research, I was able to find [this post by designer Olivia Hill](http://forum.theonyxpath.com/forum/main-category/main-forum/the-new-world-of-darkness/380418-fighting-style-merits) (emphasis added):

> Yeah. It's legacy text from before we changed the experience system.
>
> If you want 3 dots in a Style, spend 3 Experiences. If you want 5, spend 5. **It only costs 5 Experiences to get the whole Style.** Where Styles differ from other Merits is, there's a new effect at every level. Allies 5 is just Allies, but bigger than Allies 4. If Allies were a Style, Allies 5 would have five separate abilities tied to it.